# Voice Form Matching in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, sdk, nlp, voice, voice-recognition

Are there SDK's for voice-form matching / comparison for Visual C++? Or, possibly converting sounds to phonetics.

- Usage: Program will do different things from input from certain command words given in a made-up foreign language. (Klingon)
- Analysis - comparison of user's voice with existing pre-recorded voice segment

Rather than using existing text to speech SDK's, I believe I have to opt for a more general version since the language I am dealing with isn't widely supported.